# geometric inequality

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Let $A_1, A_2,\ldots, A_n$ be $n$ points on the unit circle centered at $O$. It is known that $\overline{OA_1}+\overline{OA_2}+\ldots +\overline{OA_n}=\overline{0}$.

Define the following two quantities
$$S_1=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=2}^n A_1A_j$$
and
$$S^{*}=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{1\le i<j\le n} A_iA_j.$$

Here $A_iA_j$ denotes the Euclidean distance between $A_i$ and $A_j$.

> Can one prove that $S_1+S^{*}\le 2$. (An even better bound may be possible).

[**Edit:** Fejes Tóth proved that if $n$ points lie on a unit circle then $S^∗\le\frac2\pi$, see

> Fejes Tóth, L. *On the sum of distances determined by a pointset*. Acta Math. Acad. Sci. Hungar., 7, 1956, 397–401.

On the other hand the condition that the center of gravity is located at $O$ gives easily a bound $S_1\le\sqrt2$. (Just use the fact that $\sum_{j=2}^nA_1A^2_j=2n$ and Cauchy-Schwarz). From these two, one can get an upper bound $S_1+S^∗\le\sqrt2+\frac2\pi=2.0508\dots$ But one can notice that this is not tight since if $S_1$ is close to $\sqrt2$ then $S^∗$ is close to $1/2$. I did some numerical experiments which suggest $2.0508$ can be replaced by $2$.]

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: If this isn't homework, then could you please clarify where this problem originated, what partial results or evidence you have found to suggest this inequality is true, and so on.

Comment: I have a few typos above. Fejes Toth proved that if $n$ points lie on a unit circle then $S^{*}\le \frac{2}{\pi}$. On the other hand the condition that the center of gravity is located at $O$ gives easily a bound $S_1\le \sqrt{2}$. (just use the fact that $\sum_{j=2}^n A_1A_j^2=2n$ and Cauchy_Schwarz). From these two one can get an upper bound $S_1+S^{*}\le \sqrt{2}+\frac{2}{\pi}=2.0508\ldots$. But one can notice that this is not tight since if $S_1$ is close to $\sqrt{2}$ then $S^{*}$ is close to $1/2$. I did some numerical experiments which suggest $2.0508$ can be replaced by $2$.

Comment: (@user84909, you may remove your earlier comment; then I'll try to remove one here :-).

Comment: Re the comment beginning "I have a few typos...." .... Why wasn't this in the original post?

Comment: the typos riddled message was later removed at the suggestion of one of our colleagues. The problem is highly nontrivial and far from being a "homework-type" problem. I challenge you to try to beat the 2.0508.. bound.

Comment: user84909 -- maybe I was wrong in thinking this is homework. If you edit your posting describing the motivation, known results, and maybe adding some references then I'll vote to reopen. But in general, it's probably best to avoid telling people to prove something in mo questions.

Comment: user84909:  I was asking why the content of your "I have a few typos..." comment --- i.e. the information about what's known from Fejes Toth, the information about your numerical experiments, your observations using Cauchy Schwarz --- was not in the original post.  I voted to close because you seem to have intentionally withheld this information.  I believe this could be turned into a good question if you were more forthcoming.

Comment: Also, "I challenge you to ..." No, no challenges here either. Please.

Comment: I've added your comment to the body of the question. Also, I've [asked](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/474/6085) on meta for it to be considered for reopening.

Comment: Finally, if you have references where the problem, or the bound on $S^*$, is discussed, please consider adding them to the body of the question.

Comment: Here is the relevant reference                          Fejes Tóth, L.
On the sum of distances determined by a pointset. (Russian summary)  Acta Math. Acad. Sci. Hungar 7 1956 397–401.

Comment: @user84909, instead of clicking the add comment button, consider clicking the edit button on the question.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche what is $\overline{OA_i}$?

Comment: @Turbo, why ask me?  Why not ask the OP?